# How to avoid video acquisition source message on AVD startup in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Since api revision 14 whenever I start an AVD emulator in Eclipse it ask me the acquisition source video:

[image http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/1110/avd.png](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/1110/avd.png)

How can I set up this option only once and never see again this message? Thanks.